# How to make a Discord Bot play YouTube Audio

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm a high school student making a Discord bot as a final project, and I'm having issues finding a working tutorial or baseline for playing YouTube audio in Discordpy Rewrite. If there's a tutorial I'm missing or basic code that can do this, I'd be extremely grateful for that.

I've already looked at some tutorials and tried them, but they don't seem to work for one reason or another. I've spent a lot of project time searching, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Below, I found some code for making a bot play an MP3 file, but I'm unsure how to do it using a YouTube link.

```
@bot.command()
async def mp3play(context):
  user = context.message.author
  voice_channel = user.voice.voice_channel
  channel = None
  if voice_channel != None:
    channel=voice_channel.name
    vc = await channel.connect()
    audio = vc.play("holder.mp3", after=lambda: print("Complete."))
    vc.start()
    while vc.is_playing():
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
    vc.stop()
  else:
    await ctx.send("User must be in a voice channel.")
```

Comment: What exactly is "Youtube Audio"?

Comment: @KlausD. For example, I could provide a command "$ytplay" with a link to a YouTube video, and the bot would join the voice channel and play the audio from said video.

Answer (score 4):

### Hello, some changes of methods have been made in this new version of discord.py 1.2.2, you can follow the migrations of methods in the documentation itself

---

first, you need to implement a class called `YTDLSource` to control `yotube_dl`

```py
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
```

use this class in your music command, notice that my def play belongs to other class that i call Voice.

```py
 @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        print(url)
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
```

before this, just add in your cog and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

this is all of my music bot code :

````py
import itertools
import traceback
from async_timeout import timeout
from functools import partial
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

ytdlopts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'  # ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpegopts = {
    'before_options': '-nostdin',
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdlopts)


class VoiceConnectionError(commands.CommandError):
    """Custom Exception class for connection errors."""


class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    """Exception for cases of invalid Voice Channels."""


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

    def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
        super().__init__(source)
        self.requester = requester

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.web_url = data.get('webpage_url')

        # YTDL info dicts (data) have other useful information you might want
        # https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

    def __getitem__(self, item: str):
        """Allows us to access attributes similar to a dict.
        This is only useful when you are NOT downloading.
        """
        return self.__getattribute__(item)

    @classmethod
    async def create_source(cls, ctx, search: str, *, loop, download=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        await ctx.send(f'```ini\n[Added {data["title"]} to the Queue.]\n```')

        if download:
            source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        else:
            return {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title']}

        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)

    @classmethod
    async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
        """Used for preparing a stream, instead of downloading.
        Since Youtube Streaming links expire."""
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        requester = data['requester']

        to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=False)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester)


class MusicPlayer(commands.Cog):
    """A class which is assigned to each guild using the bot for Music.
    This class implements a queue and loop, which allows for different guilds to listen to different playlists
    simultaneously.
    When the bot disconnects from the Voice it's instance will be destroyed.
    """

    __slots__ = ('bot', '_guild', '_channel', '_cog', 'queue', 'next', 'current', 'np', 'volume')

    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.bot = ctx.bot
        self._guild = ctx.guild
        self._channel = ctx.channel
        self._cog = ctx.cog

        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.next = asyncio.Event()

        self.np = None  # Now playing message
        self.volume = .5
        self.current = None

        ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

    async def player_loop(self):
        """Our main player loop."""
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            self.next.clear()

            try:
                # Wait for the next song. If we timeout cancel the player and disconnect...
                async with timeout(300):  # 5 minutes...
                    source = await self.queue.get()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return self.destroy(self._guild)

            if not isinstance(source, YTDLSource):
                # Source was probably a stream (not downloaded)
                # So we should regather to prevent stream expiration
                try:
                    source = await YTDLSource.regather_stream(source, loop=self.bot.loop)
                except Exception as e:
                    await self._channel.send(f'There was an error processing your song.\n'
                                             f'```css\n[{e}]\n```')
                    continue

            source.volume = self.volume
            self.current = source

            self._guild.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda _: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.next.set))
            self.np = await self._channel.send(f'**Now Playing:** `{source.title}` requested by '
                                               f'`{source.requester}`')
            await self.next.wait()

            # Make sure the FFmpeg process is cleaned up.
            source.cleanup()
            self.current = None

            try:
                # We are no longer playing this song...
                await self.np.delete()
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass

    def destroy(self, guild):
        """Disconnect and cleanup the player."""
        return self.bot.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))


class Music(commands.Cog):
    """Music related commands."""

    __slots__ = ('bot', 'players')

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.players = {}

    async def cleanup(self, guild):
        try:
            await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            del self.players[guild.id]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    async def __local_check(self, ctx):
        """A local check which applies to all commands in this cog."""
        if not ctx.guild:
            raise commands.NoPrivateMessage
        return True

    async def __error(self, ctx, error):
        """A local error handler for all errors arising from commands in this cog."""
        if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
            try:
                return await ctx.send('This command can not be used in Private Messages.')
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass
        elif isinstance(error, InvalidVoiceChannel):
            await ctx.send('Error connecting to Voice Channel. '
                           'Please make sure you are in a valid channel or provide me with one')

        print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)

    def get_player(self, ctx):
        """Retrieve the guild player, or generate one."""
        try:
            player = self.players[ctx.guild.id]
        except KeyError:
            player = MusicPlayer(ctx)
            self.players[ctx.guild.id] = player

        return player

    @commands.command(name='connect', aliases=['join'])
    async def connect_(self, ctx):
        try:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        except AttributeError:
            raise InvalidVoiceChannel('No channel to join.')

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if vc:
            if vc.channel.id == channel.id:
                return
            try:
                await vc.move_to(channel)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Moving to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')
        else:
            try:
                await channel.connect()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Connecting to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Joined A Call")
        embed.add_field(name="Connected To :", value=channel, inline=True)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='play', aliases=['sing', 'p'])
    async def play_(self, ctx, *, search: str):
        await ctx.trigger_typing()

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc:
            await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)

        # If download is False, source will be a dict which will be used later to regather the stream.
        # If download is True, source will be a discord.FFmpegPCMAudio with a VolumeTransformer.
        source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop, download=False)

        await player.queue.put(source)

    @commands.command(name='pause')
    async def pause_(self, ctx):
        """Pause the currently playing song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_playing():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!')
        elif vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.pause()
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Paused the song!')

    @commands.command(name='resume', aliases=['unpause'])
    async def resume_(self, ctx):
        """Resume the currently paused song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!', )
        elif not vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.resume()
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Resumed the song!')

    @commands.command(name='skip')
    async def skip_(self, ctx):
        """Skip the song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!')

        if vc.is_paused():
            pass
        elif not vc.is_playing():
            return

        vc.stop()
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Skipped the song!')

    @commands.command(name='queue', aliases=['q', 'playlist'])
    async def queue_info(self, ctx):
        """Retrieve a basic queue of upcoming songs."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently connected to voice!')

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if player.queue.empty():
            return await ctx.send('There are currently no more queued songs.')

        # Grab up to 5 entries from the queue...
        upcoming = list(itertools.islice(player.queue._queue, 0, 5))

        fmt = '\n'.join(f'**`{_["title"]}`**' for _ in upcoming)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Upcoming - Next {len(upcoming)}', description=fmt)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='now_playing', aliases=['np', 'current', 'currentsong', 'playing'])
    async def now_playing_(self, ctx):
        """Display information about the currently playing song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently connected to voice!', )

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if not player.current:
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!')

        try:
            # Remove our previous now_playing message.
            await player.np.delete()
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass

        player.np = await ctx.send(f'**Now Playing:** `{vc.source.title}` '
                                   f'requested by `{vc.source.requester}`')

    @commands.command(name='volume', aliases=['vol'])
    async def change_volume(self, ctx, *, vol: float):
        """Change the player volume.
        Parameters
        ------------
        volume: float or int [Required]
            The volume to set the player to in percentage. This must be between 1 and 100.
        """
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently connected to voice!', )

        if not 0 < vol < 101:
            return await ctx.send('Please enter a value between 1 and 100.')

        player = self.get_player(ctx)

        if vc.source:
            vc.source.volume = vol / 100

        player.volume = vol / 100
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Volume Message",
        description=f'The Volume Was Changed By **{ctx.author.name}**')
        embed.add_field(name="Current Volume", value=vol, inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        # await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Set the volume to **{vol}%**')

    @commands.command(name='stop', aliases=['leave'])
    async def stop_(self, ctx):
        """Stop the currently playing song and destroy the player.
        !Warning!
            This will destroy the player assigned to your guild, also deleting any queued songs and settings.
        """
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!')

        await self.cleanup(ctx.guild)
````